# Firebase Query Help - Double Nested

Tags: firebase

I'm attempting to query some data put can't seem to get the call just right.

Here is an example piece of the data:

```
{
    "currentSelectedPlayers" : {
        "player1" : {
            "assists" : "97",
            "currentlyPickedBy" : {
                "userID" : "641aada9-2d42-4b83-9883-ca316c842a08"
            },
            "goals" : "2",
        }
}
```

In my rules I have set:

```
"rules": {
"$currentSelectedPlayers": {
         ".indexOn": ["currentlyPickedBy", ".value"]
       }
}
```

My query: `https://{database-address}.firebaseio.com/currentSelectedPlayers.json?orderBy="$value"&equalTo="641aada9-2d42-4b83-9883-ca316c842a08"&print=pretty`

I know firebase recently introduced querying for deep nested data. How would I properly query for this nested data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `.value` index, but an index on the path ``:

```
{ 
  "currentSelectedPlayers": { 
    ".indexOn": ["currentlyPickedBy/userID"] 
  }
}
```

You can then query it with:

```
currentSelectedPlayers.json?orderBy="currentlyPickedBy/userID"&equalTo="641aada9-2d42-4b83-9883-ca316c842a08"&print=pretty
```

Give it a spin here: 
https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/34644066/currentSelectedPlayers.json?orderBy=%22currentlyPickedBy/userID%22&equalTo=%22641aada9-2d42-4b83-9883-ca316c842a08%22&print=pretty

Comment: I marked the answer as correct, thank you. What if instead of ["currentlyPickedBy/userID"]  I had something like ["currentlyPickedBy/{someUserID}" ] where someUserID was dynamic and set to true. e.g. 

"currentlyPickedBy" : {
               "641aada9-2d42-4b83-9883-ca316c842a08" : true,
               "867aada9-2d42-4b83-9883-ca316c842a08" : true
            }

Comment: That is not possible with the deep path querying, since it requires the path to be specified in the `.indexOn`. But if you're nesting lists, you should probably denormalize them into top-level lists. See this section on the docs on nesting: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-nested